# Dynamic model in partial view doesn't contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' after converting to list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I'm trying to create a partial view with a dynamic model but I get the following exception after converting the model to List

Partial View:

```
@model dynamic
@{
    dynamic model;
    var obj1ListType = new List<Obj1>().GetType();
    var obj2ListType = new List<Obj2>().GetType();
    Type unknown = Model.GetType();

    if (unknown == obj1ListType)
    {
        model = new List<Obj1>(Model);
    }
    else if (unknown == obj2ListType)
    {
        model = new List<Obj2>(Model);
    }
    else
    {
        model = new List<Obj3>(Model);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to use

```
var Obj = Model.FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following exception:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'
```

Any Ideas? Maybe another way to create a dynamic partial view?
Thanks

Comment: Try Inumerable instead of list

Comment: All of this looks really confused. XY-Problem. Ask what you want to achieve and throw this code away.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but I modified your code a bit and it works. I had to change few things. Most important change is converting the Model (actually you should have written model that you created right there) to a list and then call `FirstOrDefault()` on it.

Working Code with some adjustment:

```
@model dynamic
@{
    dynamic model;
    var obj1ListType = new List<object>().GetType();
    var obj2ListType = new List<object>().GetType();
    Type unknown = Model.GetType();

    if (unknown == obj1ListType)
    {
        model = new List<object>(Model);
    }
    else if (unknown == obj2ListType)
    {
        model = new List<object>(Model);
    }
    else
    {
        model = new List<object>(Model);
    }

    var data = model as List<object>;
    var dataItem = data.FirstOrDefault();
    <span>@dataItem</span>
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Partial1()
    {
        return View(new List<string>(){"Test1", "Test2"});
    }
```

Prints:

Test1